# I need a Jlist to popup when a file with integers is either entered or selected from JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I am using WindowBuilder in Eclipse to aid in my GUI design. I am trying to make a Jlist popup after the user either enters in a text file with integers in it or, if they enter a file that doesn't exist, they select a file with integers in it from JFileChooser. My problem I am having now is that when the file is selected, nothing happens. The program also doesn't seem to recognize when I do enter in a file that exists, it just defaults to the JFileChooser. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong and/or how to make the Jlist appear after an appropriate file is entered?

Here is the code:

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextPane;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import javax.swing.JList;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

    import java.awt.Font;

    import javax.swing.JButton;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.plaf.FileChooserUI;
    import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;

    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    public class GUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtEnterFileName;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private JList list;
    private JList list_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        txtEnterFileName = new JTextField();
        txtEnterFileName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        txtEnterFileName.setEditable(false);
        txtEnterFileName.setText("Enter File Name Below and Press Button");
        txtEnterFileName.setBounds(72, 11, 304, 41);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtEnterFileName);
        txtEnterFileName.setColumns(10);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(113, 63, 221, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int number;
                boolean endOfFile = false;
                File userF;

                userF = new File(textField.getText());

                if(!userF.exists()){
                    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                    fileChooser.setBounds(107, 153, 200, 50);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);
                    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/desktop"));
                    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
                    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        userF = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    }
                }
                else if(userF.exists()){
                    try {

                        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(userF);
                        if(inFile.hasNextLine()){
                            inFile.close();
                            fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                            fileChooser.setBounds(107, 153, 200, 50);
                            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);
                            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
                            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                                userF = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                            }
                        }
                        else if(inFile.hasNextInt()){
                            String label[] = {"Smallest Number", "Largest Number", "Count", "Average", "Median", "Quit"};
                            list = new JList(label);
                            list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                            list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
                            list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(174, 99, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);


    }
    private static void addPopup(Component component, final JPopupMenu popup) {
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }
            private void showMenu(MouseEvent e) {
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner#nextLine` always seems to return `true` so long as there some text on the first line.

So a file in the format of ...

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Will have `Scanner#nextLine` return `true`.  Instead, you should check for `hasNextInt` first and then skip over to showing the `JFileChooser`

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I replaced the 'hasNextLine' as suggested but the 'JFileChooser' still pops up when I enter a file that does exist.

Comment: And contains only numbers?